# getting item value from foreach loop in razor view to js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

i'm trying to use data i'm getting from model in razor view to an array in js in order to display multi markers on a google map.how ever what I did so far pass the data as innerHtml and the map I unable to show any markers .[image]

```
@foreach (var item in Model.UpcomingLectureGigs)
{
    <div class="well">
        <h1>blabla</h1>
        @*Parm*@
        <span class="js-latmaps">@item.Latitude </span>@*DataOk*@
        <span class="js-lngmaps">@item.Longitude </span>@*DataOk*@
        <span class="js-name">@item.Venue</span>@*DataOk*@

    </div>
}

<hr />

<div class="well">
    <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [
                    {
                        "lat": $(".js-latmaps"),
                        "lng": $('.js-lngmaps'),
                        "description": $('.js-name')
                        //"lat":37.777698,// Ok
                        // "lng":-100.0227294,//Ok
                        //"description":"myShop"//Ok
                    }
        ];
        console.log(markers);
        window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i];
                var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    get map() { return map; }
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }
        };
    </script>
```

cotroller

```
  public ActionResult Index(string query = null)
    {
        //ToDo refactor
        int myDayOfWeek = 0;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
        myDayOfWeek = (int) dt.DayOfWeek;


        var upCommingLecture = _context.LectureGigs
            .Include(g => g.Artist).Include(g => g.Genre)
            .Where(g => (g.DateTime < DateTime.Now && !g.IsCanceled
                         || (g.IsWeekLy == true
                             && (int) g.Days == (myDayOfWeek))));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
        {
            upCommingLecture = upCommingLecture
                .Where(g =>
                    g.Artist.Name.Contains(query) ||
                    g.Genre.Name.Contains(query) ||
                    g.Venue.Contains(query) ||
                    g.NewRabiName.Contains(query));
        }
        var viewModel = new GigsViewModel
        {
            UpcomingLectureGigs = upCommingLecture,
            //parm
            SearchTerm = query,
        };

        return View("index", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Convert your `UpcomingLectureGigs` property to a javascript array using `var markers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.UpcomingLectureGigs))` (note your model properties needs to be named `lat`, `lng` and `description` if you want it in the same format you have shown in `var markers = ...`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke forgive my ignorance, but how can I extract properties from var data after assuming u mean to do so in razor ?

Comment: Exactly as you are doing now - just loop through the array and access the properties of each object in the array

Comment: @StephenMuecke  <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers =[{ @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.UpcomingLectureGigs))
    
}
        ]; ? is an data reader error , I completely didn't understand u .can u please post as answer ?

Comment: No. Just exactly as per my comment (no `[{`)

Comment: var markers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.UpcomingLectureGigs));There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. (& I have remove the froeach in the view ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127481/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-assaf-our).

Answer (score 0):

Your code to pull the lat and lng are pushing the jQuery object, instead I think you'll have to do a little formatting possibly.

```
var arrLat = [];

$(".j-latmaps").each(function() {
   var lat = $(this).html();
   arrLat.push(lat);
});
```

And do the same for longitude, and then pass the array.  The center would be:

```
center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(arrLat[0], arrLng[0]),
```

Comment: using this 2 get me error at marker > :for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        var data = markers[i];